# Redux & React-router : Provider bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm starting new app using ReactJS. All the web env is quite new for me.

Anyway, I created an simple App, using react-router. Works perfectly :).

I tried to add Redux, and ... fail. I have no idea how use React-redux AND react-router.

Here's my input JS : index.js

```
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {routes}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>  <App /> </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Here's my route.js

```
export default (
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Main}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path='playerOne' header="PlayerOne" component={PromptContainer} />
      <Route path='playerTwo/:playerOne' header="PlayerTwo" component={PromptContainer} />
      <Route path='battle' component={ConfirmBattleContainer} />
      <Route path='results' component={ResultsContainer} />
      <Route path='maninthemiddle' component={ManinthemiddleContainer} />
      <Route path='button' component={ButtonContainer} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

and ofc my reducer.js

```
import reducer from './reducer.js'
import { createStore } from 'redux';


const store = createStore(reducer);

export default store;
```

And this is my error.

> Uncaught Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element > child

and my warning :

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `array` supplied >  >  to `Provider`, expected a single ReactElement.

I know that Provider have to be on "top" of the app, but it's exactly what I did. I'm lost :(

Thanks for your helps guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the whitespace around <App />.  This:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>  <App /> </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

should be:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

the spaces in there are being treated as text nodes, i.e. additional children.

Comment: @GreGGus - hello!  if my answer indeed fixed your error/warning, could you please accept it as answered?  thank you!